# Nested array in JSON object, add key if not exists and value as empty

Tags: javascript, json, nested-loops

Currently, I have a nested array in JSON object. I would like to define the key and value for the following:

- contact as `"phone": "", "email" : "", "fax": "", "website": ""`
- address as `"city": "", "country": "", "house_number": "", "street name": ""`

If one of these keys is missing, it needs to be filled as a default key and value as shown in the expected input.

Could anyone help how to do it in JavaScript?

Current Input:

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "John",
      "contact": {
        "phone": "987-654-3210",
        "email": "john123@xyz.com"
      },
      "address": {
        "city": "Berlin",
        "country": "Germany"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected Input:

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "John",
      "contact": {
        "phone": "987-654-3210",
        "email": "john123@xyz.com",
        "fax": "",
        "website": ""
      },
      "address": {
        "city": "Berlin",
        "country": "Germany",
        "house_number": "",
        "street name": ""
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+add+default+to+nested+object+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind to mutate your original array, here's one solution:

```js
const templates = {
  contact: {
    "phone": "",
    "email": "",
    "fax": "",
    "website": ""
  },
  address: {
    "city": "",
    "country": "",
    "house_number": "",
    "street name": ""
  }
}

source.data.forEach(entry => Object.entries(templates).forEach(([key, template]) => {
  entry[key] = entry[key] || {};
  Object.entries(template).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    entry[key][k] = entry[key][k] || v;
  });
}));
```

```js
const source = {
  "data": [{
    "name": "John",
    "contact": {
      "phone": "987-654-3210",
      "email": "john123@xyz.com"
    },
    "address": {
      "city": "Berlin",
      "country": "Germany"
    }
  }, {
    "name": "Bob",
    "contact": {
      "phone": "123-456-7890",
      "fax": "9876-5432",
      "website": "bob.example.com"
    },
    "address": {
      "city": "NYC",
      "country": "USA",
      "house_number": "701A"
    }
  }]
};

const templates = {
  contact: {
    "phone": "",
    "email": "",
    "fax": "",
    "website": ""
  },
  address: {
    "city": "",
    "country": "",
    "house_number": "",
    "street name": ""
  }
}

source.data.forEach(entry => Object.entries(templates).forEach(([key, template]) => {
  entry[key] = entry[key] || {};
  Object.entries(template).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    entry[key][k] = entry[key][k] || v;
  });
}));

console.log(source);
```

Comment: Hao Wu thank you for solution, i have tried but not working because there is warning on "expected identifier and instead saw '??' ". Any other alternative solution ?

Comment: That means your environment doesn't support [nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing), I've replaced it with a more compatible syntax.

Comment: It's work as expected thank you.

Comment: `Hao Wu` i have another question related on this question above. If source giving input for object key of 'contact' only, then use only 'contact' template, If source giving input for object key of 'address' only, then use only 'address' template. Otherwise both object key template include. How could implement that method ?

Comment: Then replace `entry[key] = entry[key] || {};` with `if (!entry[key]) return;` should do the trick.